# Disabling parse notifications

Tags: android, eclipse, parse-platform, application-settings

I'm using parse.com for push notifications in my app. I added a "disable notifications" option to application settings like this:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Obvestila" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="prefNotification"
        android:summary="Za obvestila je potrebna internetna povezava"
        android:title="Prejemal obvestila" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

And then added this method to MainActivity:

```
public void getSettingsPrefs(){
    SharedPreferences settingsPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    notification = settingsPrefs.getBoolean("prefNotification", true);

    if (notification == false)
    {
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, null);
    }
    else
    {
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that this only partly works. Once I check or uncheck the box in the settings, I need to completely re-open the MainActivity so that the getSettingsPrefs() is executed in onCreate. How do I make the IF statement execute everytime the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself by adding OnPreferenceChangeListener.

```
notification = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("prefNotification");
    notification.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            if (newValue.toString().equals("true"))
            {
                notificationsOn();
            }
            else
            {
                notificationsOff();
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```